# Missing pyqt5 module in the exe file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, exe

I am working with pyqt5 with python.
I finished programming the code then I wanted to convert my tool into `exe` file.
When I run this `exe` file it showed no:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

As shown in the picture below:

[from_main.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6glrR.png)

Can you guide me, please?

Comment: Create a [example] and explain how you are converting to an exe \

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the converter works in the python version that you installed the libraries in , and that you work in.

After that convert the application into exe as one file.

After that make sure that your application is in place it does not need any permissions to do anything in your system.

After that see what will happen.